# dual boot linux on windows

Tags: dual-boot

I installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a separate hard disk. And now I can't boot into Linux and Windows boots automatically. And in the BIOS system, I can't also see Linux as a boot option. I also tried the [EasyBCD](https://www.filecroco.com/download-easybcd/download/) software to add Linux but using the software I couldn't  add Linux as an entry.

Comment: Disable secure boot and fast startup. Then boot with a live USB and run the command `sudo update-grub`. If that does not work try recommended repair with [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I have already disabled secure boot and fast startup. But I am not sure what to do next. I am now trying to boot with a live USB and I am selecting try Ubunt Without Install. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, boot with a live USB and select try Ubuntu without installing. Then open a terminal and run the command `sudo update-grub`. Edit: I just realized from your answer that you have solved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, thanks though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess since I installed ubuntu on a seperate hard disk, I could see ubuntu as an option by booting to the BIOS and in the "Boot" tab I selected "selecting "UFEI Hard Disk Drive BBS priorities" and here I changed Ubuntu to be the first option. and problem solved now I am presented with a list to choose from(windows or linux).

Answer (score 0):

Try booting in the bios to the linux drive. A GRUB menu should open and your choices are availible there. If this works, set the default boot drive to the linux drive

Comment: how can I do so "booting in the bios to the linux drive." ?

Comment: Going into your BOIS boot options, how you do that depends on your motherboard manufacture (msi uses F11), and select the drive Linux is installed to